# Подскажите скрипт перезапуска ffmpeg при обрыве интернета

Tags: ffmpeg

Подскажите скрипт перезапуска ffmpeg при обрыве интернета, вот строка запуска:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 0 -i входной поток -c:v libx264 -deinterlace -timecode 01:02:03:04 -s 500x300 -r 25 -vb 220k -profile:v baseline -preset:v superfast -tune zerolatency -c:a libmp3lame  -b:a 11k -ac 2 -ar 11025 -f flv "rtmp://выходной поток flashver=FMLE/3.0\20(compatible;\20FMSc/1.0) authmod=llnw  live=1 playpath="
```

Если случается обрыв интернета кратковременный или какие то проблемы с сетью то ffmpeg зависает, и при включении интернета он так и висит и не возобновляет кодирование, а нужно что бы он перезапустился и дальше продолжил свою работу

Comment: Вы его случайно не в связке с nginx используете?

Comment: нет, nginx там нет, но если есть решение с ним, то установлю

Comment: Ну, я вижу, что поток у вас в rtmp идет. Значит, должен быть сервер трансзяции. Что у вас за сервер?

Comment: поток идет на сторонний медиа-сервер, а ffmpeg запускаю на Ubuntu

Comment: а при падении, ffmpeg падает?

Comment: он зависает, процес висит с тем же pid но не кодирует

Comment: @Стас ffmpeg на Ubuntu нужно перезапускать если с Ubuntu не пингуется только сторонний сервер или вообще пропал и появился интернет?

Comment: @Стас и еще: для выполнения указанной команды нужны привилегии root?

Comment: нужно перезапускать когда вообще пропал и появился интернет, все права root есть

Answer (score 1):

У ffmpeg большая любовь к зависанию при пропадании потока. Я бы попытал счастья с gstreamer для начала.

Он поддерживает все необходимые фрагменты конвейера, так что поэкспериментировав, можно подобрать неплохие параметры.

Comment: спасибо, но пока это не вариант, нужно искать решение для ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Увы, для данного сценария FFMPEG является самым неустойчивым инструментом, есть альтернативные решения для обхода проблемы с обрывом интернета:

Грубый вариант: обернуть ваш ffmpeg в bash-скрипт и мониторить отдельным скриптом интернет-статус (простой пинг внешки каждый 5-10 сек.), в случае обрыва "убивать" (перезапускать) скрипт, и запускать заново, как только возобновится интернет. И ещё не ясен фактор обрыва сети: насколько я понимаю, проблемы возникают на стороне ре-стримера, т. е. откуда вы пытаетесь запустить ffmpeg, и "**входной поток**" тянется с того же сервера.

Правильный и более fault-tolerant вариант — использование **Gstreamer** пакета, упомянутого пользователем @gbg, т. к. пакет использует pipeline методы и создаёт своего рода listener сокета. Достаточно будет установить *gst-plugins-bad, gst-plugins-good, gst-plugins-base* плагины.